# Parsing incoming LDAP filter with perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to write a LDAP server with Net::LDAP::Server

The request routing/handling works fine, but the parsing of the incoming ldap filter causes me some troubles.

The incoming filter has this value/structure:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'and' => [
                     {
                       'or' => [
                                 {
                                   'substrings' => {
                                                     'substrings' => [
                                                                       {
                                                                         'initial' => '233'
                                                                       }
                                                                     ],
                                                     'type' => 'sn'
                                                   }
                                 },
                                 {
                                   'substrings' => {
                                                     'substrings' => [
                                                                       {
                                                                         'initial' => '233'
                                                                       }
                                                                     ],
                                                     'type' => 'sn'
                                                   }
                                 },
                                 {
                                   'equalityMatch' => {
                                                        'assertionValue' => '233',
                                                        'attributeDesc' => 'telephoneNumber'
                                                      }
                                 },
                                 {
                                   'equalityMatch' => {
                                                        'assertionValue' => '233',
                                                        'attributeDesc' => 'telephoneNumber'
                                                      }
                                 }
                               ]
                     }
                   ]
        };
```

Here my code to parse the LDAP filter

```
my $myFilter= $reqData->{'filter'};
print STDERR "Filter : $myFilter \n";
print STDERR Dumper($myFilter) ."\n";
my @andloop= $myFilter->{'and'};
my $and;

foreach $and(@andloop) 
{
    print STDERR "Filter AND: $and \n";
    print STDERR Dumper($and) ."\n";

    my $orValue;

    foreach $orValue ($and) 
    {
        print STDERR "Inside Filter OR: $orValue : $and\n";
        print STDERR "Keys: ";
        print STDERR Dumper($orValue) . "\n";
        print STDERR "KeysOR: ";

        my @or= $orValue;

        print STDERR Dumper(@or[0]->{'or'}) . "\n";
        print STDERR "OR Value[0]: " . Dumper(@or[0]) . "\n";
    }
}
```

I can loop via the AND, but don't seem to dive down into the 'or' parts

Comment: You are mixing up references and arrays.

Comment: `print STDERR` is more simply written as `warn`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$orValue` is an array reference. Dereference it to get a real array:

```
my @or = @$orValue;
```

You need to be more careful with references, they (usually) don't dereference automatically:

```
print STDERR "Filter : $myFilter \n";
print STDERR Dumper($myFilter), "\n";

for my $and (@{ $myFilter->{and} }) {
    print STDERR "Filter AND: $and \n";
    print STDERR Dumper($and) ."\n";

    for my $or (@{ $and->{or} }) {
        print STDERR "Inside Filter OR: $or : $and\n";
        print STDERR "Keys: ";
        print STDERR Dumper($or), "\n";
    }
}
```